# Html alt cuts the word with space shown as tooltip

Tags: html, jsp

I have a word like "log out" which is shown as tooltip using alt and title tags.when i mouse hover on the **logout** image only **log** is displayed **no out**. when i inspect the div tag its displayed as :

<...title="log" out="" alt="log" out<="" a="">

```
      <a href="delog.jsp" target="fraTra"><img src="images/header/deconnexion.png" width="16" height="16" border="no" title=<%=lLogout%> alt=<%=lLogout%></a>
```

How can i get the whole word as a tooltip.

Thanks

Sekhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Attribute values containing spaces must be surrounded by single or double quote characters

Change `alt=log out` to `alt="log out"`.